# Distinct query shows error?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT AA,BB FROM TAB_1;

SELECT BB,DISTINCT AA FROM TAB_1;
```

First query dose not show error while second shows:

> `ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"`

Comment: Please read some book and check if the statement is actaully correct.

Comment: You simply do not know how to use Oracle yet. Not a place to learn.

Comment: or duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701234/using-distinct-for-specific-columns

Comment: To be fair, if you are completely new to SQL and for some reason assume `DISTINCT` is a function, it might not be obvious from [the SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55272) that it is not. (The key railroad diagram is [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDDCHGF).)

Comment: Thanks a lots Sudipta Mondal

Answer (score 1):

Use this [syntax](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/distinct.php)

```
SELECT DISTINCT expressions
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```

Comment: @l3rutt - Its always better to post links from Standard Oracle docs and not 3rd party websites.

Comment: @Sudipta Mondal Take into consideration